# Cannot import module pysftp in AWS glue endpoint machine (PyCharm)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, pycharm, aws-glue

When trying to do some tests using a python script inside an endpoint, I'm running out of options to be able to have the pysftp module working.
I'm using PyCharm and everytime I try to install the package it fails with:

[image]

I connected to the machine, tried to install the pysftp, but I was not able to do that due to permissions. I installed using a command "pip install pysftp --user" and it installed, but still when I run the code, it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysftp'".
The script is being executed with /usr/bin/gluepython3.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the pysftp location to your PythonPath?

Comment: @RobertKossendey, after installed it with the "--user" option?

Comment: yes exactly. can you try that?